# ScriptResource.axd was not found

Tags: asp.net, scriptresource.axd

A couple weeks ago I made a change and added some javascript to one of my aspx pages and it worked for me until I released the file to the network, now it works on the live server, but not on my localhost server that it makes when I build the site.. if I cannot find a fix, I am going to just take out the javascript, since in my reading I have found that ScriptResource.axd has something to do with handling javascript.

But I would really like to save that as the last possibility

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few web forms you can visit that discuss this issue, that are still current, and from my experiance removing the javascript won't just simply fix the problem, something has gotten messed up possibly in your web.config file. If not that find out which pages this error is specific to and try re working the code a little.
Hope I can offer some help

http://web.archive.org/web/20120210224523/http://csharpquestions.com/asp-net/when-scriptresource-axd-suddenly-404s

-that one is the one i found to be somewhat helpful.

Comment: After "reworking" the one file that was having this problem, actually all i did was get the latest version from our sourcesafe, it fixed it.. don't know why I didnt try that before... 
Thanks